# Inequality about Frobenius norms for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

For any square matrix A, but not necessarily symmetric, what are some ways  to prove the inequality
$$
\|A^2\|_F^2\leq\|A^TA\|_F^2,
$$
where $\|B\|_F^2=tr(B^TB)$ is the Frobenius norm of matrix $B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$\langle M,N\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(M^T N)$ is an inner product on the space of $n\times n$ matrices, and induces the Frobenius norm, so
$$
\|A^2\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}(A^T A^T A A)
= \operatorname{tr}(A^T A A A^T) = \langle A^T A, AA^T\rangle
\le \|A^T A\|_F \|AA^T\|_F
$$
by Cauchy-Schwarz.  By similar manipulations, you can check that $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ have the same norm, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks very much. Really appreciate it. This solves my problem.